# BottomSheetBehavior is not a child of CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

this is my XML layout with name songlist :

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="308dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/personlog"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is my fragment which contain this layout :

```
public class SongList extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songlist,container,false);

        textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt);

        View bottomSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(200);
return view;}
}
```

but when lunch the app give me this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout
```

from this line :

```
  BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
```

how can fix this ? seems all things work fine but give that error ... if any one can please help

Comment: so how can made this layout with true way ? if u have some solution please answer

Comment: i add NestedScrollView inside CoordinatorLayout but still same problem

Comment: can understand your point . if you want help me please answer my question not comment then tell me where code must be change to what or some thing like that . tnx

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [`BottomSheetBehavior`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html) is

> An interaction behavior plugin for a child view of CoordinatorLayout to make it work as a bottom sheet.

At the moment you bottom sheet `NestedScrollView` is a child of `LinearLayout`. So just drop the outer-most `LinearLayout` all completely.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="308dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/personlog"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But now you have some more issues with the bottom sheet you're trying to implement. Firstly you should not use `wrap_content` with a scroll view. Secondly you should not use a list view inside a scroll view, since it's implementing its own scrolling. You might be able to simplify this by only using the list view as a bottom sheet.

Comment: There is also a linearlayout containing a single listview.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using data binding and including the layout to the fragment you have to do like following

```
val sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(binding.layoutBottomSheet.root)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note, if you don't use a CoordinatorLayout and instead use the BottomSheetDialogFragment (which makes one for you), I noticed that you cannot navigate to that dialog fragment with Fragment directions using the current version of the Nav component library (2.1.0-alpha05) and must instantiate it as a new fragment dialog otherwise you get this error, i.e. instead of using this:

`navController().navigate(MerchantHistoryFragmentDirections.showDateSelection())`

You must use this:

```
fragmentManager?.let {
            val dateSelection = DateSelectionFragment.newInstance()
            dateSelection.setTargetFragment(this, RC_DATE_SELECTION)
            dateSelection.show(it)
        }
```

It's a kind of obtuse error so hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have used the following solution to solve the issue

```
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    dialog.setOnShowListener { dialogInterface ->
        val bottomSheetDialog = dialogInterface as BottomSheetDialog
        setupFullHeight(bottomSheetDialog)
    }
    return dialog
}

  val bottomSheet = bottomSheetDialog
            .findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
    val behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*>?
    if (bottomSheet != null) {
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        behavior.isDraggable = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
```

I used `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` (in a fragment or activity that contains a layout and a BottomSheet).

Answer (score 0):

you should change your layout design to
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

it works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You must cast your view to `View` for example:

[See on github](https://github.com/FirstVoyager/Android-development-with-example/blob/187bff120351191e605acfbcf6a9a83a2fdaf307/app/src/main/java/limitless/android/androiddevelopment/BottomSheet/FullScreenBotttomSheer.java#L24)

Answer (score -1):

you have to set your bottom sheet layout in appbar layout below your content layout